# Read local file and convert to JSON format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm a novice.  I know enough (or can research enough) to cobble together websites for my own use.

My current project includes populating a dropdown menu from contents of a file located on the server in the same directory as my index.html. Then, I need to convert that into a JSON format required by the jQuery plugin (ddSlick: http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick).

The JSON format is:

```
var data = [
{
    text: "Facebook",
    value: 1,
    description: "Description with Facebook",
    imageSrc: "http://i.imgur.com/1.jpg"
},
{
    text: "Twitter",
    value: 2,
    description: "Description with Twitter",
    imageSrc: "http://i.imgur.com/2.jpg"
},
];
```

The file is currently a .txt file with the following format, but I am willing to use any file type and/or structure:

```
name1 value1 description1 imagesource1
name2 value2 description2 imagesource2
```

The search results on this topic weren't particularly helpful.

Thanks in advance for your help!
Scott

Comment: you'll want AJAX

Comment: See [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) - I would definitely recommend you use some supported format for your input data; csv or something light like that – it will make it easier to convert to JSON